# CakePHP read PDF generated and send it as bytes

Tags: php, file, cakephp, pdf

In my webapp, I can generate pdf file from multiple odt files using gedooo on demand when the user go to this url: `http://{base_url}/models/generer/{doc_id}`, the modelsController generate the pdf and launch the download on the navigator.

Now I have to send to a distant application by webservice the content of pdf (like an attachment in email) from a model. The problem is to execute the pdf generation and integrate it in my request without store it on the server as file. I tried to do something like:

```
$pdf = new File('http://{base_url}/models/generer/{doc_id}');
$content = $pdf->read();
```

And I get an error. I am out of ideas, I need your help.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

```
$this->requestAction($url);
```

that write the file in the folder of my webapp and

```
$content = file_get_contents($local_url)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not transmit PDF (binary file).

if you want to transmit it in webservice, you have to convert it to base64

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://{base_url}/models/generer/{doc_id}');
$filedata = base64_encode($file);
```

now you can send this data in webservice

```
echo json_encode(array('file'=>$filedata));
```

Comment: If you have security then you have to make that page either public or accessible by token based login.